# jQuery - Error in parsing value 'opacity' with .animate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity

I made a simple jQuery script to fade in, and fade out divs containing text. It works fine in practice, but I get this error as at some point opacity exceeds regular value range
I must say I'm really a novice when it comes to javascrpt and jQuery

```
function haikuSwitch(){
var $active = $("#haikuwrapper .haiku.active");
if ($active.lenght == 0) $active = $("#haikuwrapper .haiku:first");

var $next
$sibl = $active.siblings();
if ($sibl.lenght == 0) $next = $("#haikuwrapper .haiku:last");
else {
    var randnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibl.length );
    $next = $( $sibl[ randnum ] );
}

$active.animate({'opacity': 0}, 2000)
    .css({'z-index': '10'})
    .removeClass('active');

$next.css({ 'opacity': 0, 'z-index': '10'})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({'opacity': 1}, 2000);
    }

$(function() {
  $("#haikuwrapper .haiku:first").addClass('active')
    .css({ 'opacity': 1, 'z-index' : '10'});
      setInterval( "haikuSwitch()", 10000 );
    });
```

I can't find where this problem originates. Help?

Comment: 1.Did u see any errors in your browser ? I see there are spelling mistakes for 'length' as 'lenght' ????
2.Did u close the function haikuSwitch ?
3.Dont complicate the code by having $(function(){}); ...the content of this function will work without any anoymous function wraps

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with the ranges for opacity.

I see a **syntax error though**... You have misspelled `height`

`$active.lenght` supposed to be `$active.length`

One place I think it throws an error would be  `$next` when `empty or null`

So adding a check condition for that selector should be a good idea..

```
$next.length && $next.css({ 'opacity': 0, 'z-index': '10'})
```

Comment: Ah, I did indeed! Thanks!
However isn't the **if / else** bit enough to make sure $next is always existing?